# Passing in boolean and returning a string in TypeScript

Tags: string, typescript, boolean

I am struggling with a problem in TypeScript and I was wondering if someone can help me out.
Can anyone help? I am currently learning TypeScript and using an if/else statement or a switch statement was what initially came to mind first.

**Problem:** Complete the method that takes a boolean value and returns a "YES" if true and "NO" if false.

```
export const boolToWord = (bool: boolean): string => {
  throw new Error("Not implemented!");
};
```

This is the first solution I came up with was using an if/else statement and that did not work.

```
export const boolToWord = (bool: boolean): string => {
 if(true){
    return "Yes"
 } else if (false) {
    return "No"
 } else if {
   return "Not Implemented"
 }
};
boolToWord(True);
```

I also tried using a switch statement, but that did not work.

```
export const boolToWord = (bool: boolean): string => {
  switch(boolean){
    case: true;
    console.log("YES");
    break;
    case: false;
    console.log("NO");
    break;
    case: error;
    console.log("Not Implemented")
    break;
   }
};
boolToWord(True);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
return bool ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

Comment: Yes.  If the boolean that is passed it true, then I want it returning "YES". If the boolean is false, then I want it returning "NO"